# Oracle Reverse Primary Keys

Tags: oracle, indexing, reverse

I am trying to create a table with a reverse index on my primary key column.

The table is created, and I have inserted a lot of data, generating a key value with a sequence.

From what I understand about reverse keys, about how it gets the nextval and reverses it, then inserts...I was expecting to see the key value reversed in my select statement.

If nextval was 112, when i select from the table i was expecting to see 211. But i still see 112.

Is it still implementing the reverse key index, and Oracle is just displaying in non-reversed format?

Or is something actually wrong?

The SQL i used for the index is

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "<schema>"."<index_name>" ON "<schema>"."<table_name>" ("SYS_I") REVERSE;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reverse key index does not change a key value.
Only it's physical representation stored on the disk is changed.
From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1181)

> **Reverse Key Indexes**
>
> A reverse key index is a type of B-tree index **that physically reverses the bytes of each index key while keeping the
>   column order.** For example, if the index key is 20, and if the two
>   bytes stored for this key in hexadecimal are C1,15 in a standard
>   B-tree index, then a reverse key index stores the bytes as 15,C1.
>
> Reversing the key solves the problem of contention for leaf blocks in
>   the right side of a B-tree index. This problem can be especially acute
>   in an Oracle Real Application Clusters (Oracle RAC) database in which
>   multiple instances repeatedly modify the same block. For example, in
>   an orders table the primary keys for orders are sequential. One
>   instance in the cluster adds order 20, while another adds 21, with
>   each instance writing its key to the same leaf block on the right-hand
>   side of the index.
>
> In a reverse key index, the reversal of the byte order distributes
>   inserts across all leaf keys in the index. For example, keys such as
>   20 and 21 that would have been adjacent in a standard key index are
>   now stored far apart in separate blocks. Thus, I/O for insertions of
>   sequential keys is more evenly distributed.
>
> Because the data in the index is not sorted by column key when it is
>   stored, the reverse key arrangement eliminates the ability to run an
>   index range scanning query in some cases. For example, if a user
>   issues a query for order IDs greater than 20, then the database cannot
>   start with the block containing this ID and proceed horizontally
>   through the leaf blocks.